# I would like to be able to print a specific series of Web pages as one document (preferably PDF).

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, save

All I have found online is about printing individual Web pages one at a time.

The reason is that our website currently has a number of "publications" on it (ranging from 15 to 50 individual Web pages each). Before the Web, we printed and sold them

What we're doing now is producing a series of Web pages on each topic. Then we go back to the original in MS Word and make that into a multipage PDF, linked to the page.

We would really prefer to only do things once -- easier to update and fewer errors.

I know it's possible in some CMS's (such as Drupal) to arrange a series of Web pages as a "book" so that the entire thing can be printed. What I want to know is whether there's any *other* way to do this (since we aren't using Drupal).

If there's a way to put code into the page that says "If someone presses this button, print this list of pages as one PDF" I'd like to know how. (HTML? JavaScript? something else?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.

- The button would need to make a request to the server with the identifiers of the selected pages to generate
- The server then would need to render the pages internally into an object such as string. (whatever your library prefers)
- You then can send the HTML string to a PDF converter such as [Expert Pdf Html To Pdf Converter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExpertPdfHtmlToPdf/9.2.2) to generate a PDF rendition of the document.
- Then just serve the PDF binary as a response to the client.